# Difference between Linear Mixed Regression and Generalized Estimating Equation Results

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, generalized-estimating-equations

I am using commonly available iris dataset and trying to do following regression:

PW ~ PL + SL + SW

Since samples are taken from 3 "Species", this is kept as random or group variable.

The results of Linear Mixed Regression are:

```
        Mixed Linear Model Regression Results
=====================================================
Model:            MixedLM Dependent Variable: PW     
No. Observations: 150     Method:             REML   
No. Groups:       3       Scale:              0.0278 
Min. group size:  50      Log-Likelihood:     41.4680
Max. group size:  50      Converged:          Yes    
Mean group size:  50.0                               
-----------------------------------------------------
           Coef.  Std.Err.   z    P>|z| [0.025 0.975]
-----------------------------------------------------
Intercept   0.082    0.335  0.245 0.807 -0.575  0.740
SL         -0.098    0.045 -2.199 0.028 -0.186 -0.011
SW          0.238    0.048  4.975 0.000  0.144  0.332
PL          0.257    0.050  5.139 0.000  0.159  0.355
Group Var   0.257    1.636                           
=====================================================
```

While the results of GEE regression are:

```
                               GEE Regression Results                              
===================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                          PW   No. Observations:                  150
Model:                                 GEE   No. clusters:                        3
Method:                        Generalized   Min. cluster size:                  50
                      Estimating Equations   Max. cluster size:                  50
Family:                           Gaussian   Mean cluster size:                50.0
Dependence structure:         Independence   Num. iterations:                     2
Date:                     Thu, 16 Jul 2020   Scale:                           0.037
Covariance type:                    robust   Time:                         02:42:49
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Intercept     -0.2403      0.151     -1.595      0.111      -0.536       0.055
SL            -0.2073      0.088     -2.349      0.019      -0.380      -0.034
SW             0.2228      0.073      3.036      0.002       0.079       0.367
PL             0.5241      0.049     10.711      0.000       0.428       0.620
==============================================================================
Skew:                          0.2232   Kurtosis:                       0.9437
Centered skew:                -0.2824   Centered kurtosis:              1.2493
==============================================================================
=============== cov_struct.summary() ===============
Observations within a cluster are modeled as being independent.
```

Although P-values for all 3 predictor variables are significant in both, they are different in 2 analyses.

Moreover, the coefficients are quite different:

[image]

Which of these analyses is more appropriate and acceptable? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You probably just need to change the correlation structure toe `exchangeable`. The estimates won't be exactl the same but they should be very close.

Comment: Firstly, I did some more reading about GEE on the net. As you also wrote earlier, it is used if dependent variable is `count` data. Since PW here is an continuous numeric `interval` variable, GEE is not appropriate and Mixed Linear Model should be done. Is that correct? Secondly, when should I use `cov_struct=Exchangable()` with GEE?

Comment: You can still use GEE for a linear model, but the results should be the same (or very similar) to a mixed model is you use the right correlation structure. I will write an answer soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I fit these models in R I get very similar estimates to those that you obtained:

```
> data("iris")

> # lmm
> m.lmm <- lmer(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + (1|Species), data = iris)
> m.gee <- geeglm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, id = Species, data = iris, corstr = "independence")
> summary(m.lmm)

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    0.0821     0.3356    0.24
Sepal.Length  -0.0984     0.0444   -2.22
Sepal.Width    0.2380     0.0477    4.99
Petal.Length   0.2567     0.0478    5.37

> summary(m.gee)

 Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.err   Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)   -0.2403  0.1506   2.55   0.1106    
Sepal.Length  -0.2073  0.0882   5.52   0.0188 *  
Sepal.Width    0.2228  0.0734   9.22   0.0024 ** 
Petal.Length   0.5241  0.0489 114.72   <2e-16 ***
```

The diffeence is mostle due to using `independence` as the correlation structure. To be equivalent to the mixed model you should use `exchangable`:

```
> m.gee1 <- geeglm(Petal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, id = Species, data = iris, corstr="exchangeable")
> summary(m.gee1)

 Coefficients:
             Estimate Std.err  Wald Pr(>|W|)    
(Intercept)    0.0767  0.1960  0.15    0.695    
Sepal.Length  -0.1015  0.0254 16.02  6.3e-05 ***
Sepal.Width    0.2357  0.0958  6.06    0.014 *  
Petal.Length   0.2647  0.0332 63.45  1.7e-15 ***
```

Exchangeable correlation structure means that the residual covariance between all species is the same, which is the same assumption as in mixed effects models.

Comment: So GEE can be used for all kinds of data, while Mixed Linear Models can be used for continuous numeric (interval or ratio) data only. Mixed linear model is not for binary or count data. Is that correct?

Comment: No. If the response is (conditionally) normal then you can use a LMM. If the distribution of the conditional response is an exponential family distribution (e.g. Poisson,  Binomial, Gamma) then you would use a GLMM (with the appropriate link function). GEE can be (and most often is) compared to GLMM because they are not equivalent.