# Treating Categorical Variables as Continuous for Random Forest / Adaboost

Tags: scikit-learn, cart, categorical-encoding, ensemble-learning, adagrad

What's the correct way to deal with categorical variables in packages like sklearn's RF and xgboost?

Is there any cons of treating the variables are continuous? E.g. encode class A as 1, class B as 2, class C as 3?

Comment: To so would normally be a serious error!

Comment: Makes sense, so would the correct way be:
1. make data into category
2. make it sparse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels)

Comment: You could get some ideas from: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/390671/random-forest-regression-with-sparse-data-in-python/430127#430127, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/410939/label-encoding-vs-dummy-variable-one-hot-encoding-correctness/414729#414729, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231285/dropping-one-of-the-columns-when-using-one-hot-encoding/329281#329281