# Decision Tree vs Regression for Multiple Categorical Inputs

Tags: regression, cart, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I have a problem with multiple categorical inputs.  These categories do not intuitively map to integers, while preserving their adjacent relationship.
Does it make more sense to us a Decision Tree than Linear Regression given this fact?  I am getting very high validation error on my LR model with encoded categories, and significantly lower with a Decision Tree.

Im wondering, in practice, if multiple categorical values with the relationship outlined above prevents Linear Regression from being a good model, even after encoding.

Comment: Did you try the standard encoding with dummy variables (one per category, without reference category)?

Comment: Yes, I have represented all categorical values with integers.  'American' and 'Italian' map to 0 and 1, for example, which doesnt make sense when constructing a coefficient for that term in the Linear Regression.

Comment: Just replacing labels by integers is not the same as dummy coding. There, you represent each label by an own column.

Comment: I have 75+ categories...

Comment: Is it possible to group the categories thematically (without statistics) in few groups and represent each group by a dummy?

Comment: The curse of dimensionality...

Comment: @MichaelM, no that is not possible.  Im wondering if you can simply address the question outlined in the OP.  Are Decision Trees better for modeling categorical values?

Comment: What does "These categories do not intuitively map to integers, while preserving their adjacent relationship." mean?

Answer (score 0):

You say you represented the category levels *by integers*. That is **not** the same as using dummy encoding! and **should not be done**. This error probably explains why a decision tree gave much better results. Try again, but now using dummy encoding.

You hint in comments about 75+ categories (better to say *levels*), why is that a problem? If you represent the design matrix using sparse matrices, storage should not be a problem.  If too many parameters compared to $n$ is the problem, use some form of *regularization*. You could mine [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels) for ideas.