# Multi level with a single dummy

Tags: regression, econometrics, prediction, categorical-encoding, many-categories

Can someone explain me the problems associated with using more than 20 levels in a single dummy variables.

I am aware of the negative implications of using several dummies variables in a model. However recently I came across a reading that mentioned usage of several level with a single dummy category also has negative implications.i.e it can affect the estimates of other predictor coefficients.

When I experimentally tried it with a data set, I found that coefficients of other predictors are indeed distorted to a larger scale if I cut the number of levels from 20 to 15. ( Data set: I had 3 predictors and one dummy variable having 20 levels)

Can someone explain shortcomings of multilevel dummies.

Comment: How many observations do you have per level of the categorical predictor?

Comment: around 200 observations per level

Answer (score 0):

This question is really to broad, and you should have told us a reference for the claim that *usage of several level with a single dummy category also has negative implications.i.e it can affect the estimates of other predictor coefficients*.  Assuming a regression model you want to use for prediction, a dummy with 20 levels eats up $20-1$ df (degrees of freedom), so this is just the problem of having to estimate many parameters. Without some more context, this is no different from having too many continuous predictors.

*If* this turns out to be a problem, you can look to [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels)   for ideas for solutions.