# Label-encoding nominal variables

Tags: python, categorical-data, data-transformation, categorical-encoding, labeling

I am aware of the practice that `label encoding` is preferred for `ordinal variables` while `one-hot encoding` is done for `nominal variables`. **But what if we `label encode` nominal variables?** Will it have any **negative impact** on modeling or prediction?

For eg -

```
>>> data['Card_Category'].unique()
... array(['Blue', 'Gold', 'Silver', 'Platinum'], dtype=object)
>>> card_mapping = {'Blue': 0, 'Gold': 1, 'Silver': 2, 'Platinum': 3}
>>> data['Card_Category'].replace(card_mapping, inplace=True)
```

> Instead of using one-hot encoding, I have used label encoding. Thoughts on this?

Comment: Where does this practice come from? I can't think of an algorithm that would internally treat labels differently from  one-hot encoding. Actually (my guess, since I haven't seen all the source code) I believe labels are internally translated into one-hot encoding (or dummy variables, but to the same effect). So it should make no difference for you. However, neither of these is actually advisable for ordinal variables, as you lose the information about the relationship between the values.

Comment: @IgorF. Can you elaborate on the part **Algorithms internally treat labels as one-hot encoding** ?

Comment: See e.g.:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77880/55122 , 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/411767/232706 , 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/410939/232706 , 

As for implementations as @IgorF. addresses, it depends.  See e.g. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/87403/55122

Comment: @BenReiniger OK, thanks, I think I misinterpreted the question. @AmitPathak Sorry, I'm not an expert on `sklearn` implementation.