# Encode categorical variables with many labels

Tags: categorical-data, categorical-encoding, many-categories

I am trying to predict a multiclass categorical outcome variable by comparing different classifier algorithms. 
I've got a dataset that includes two categorical variables that have many labels (>2000). The problem is that the proportion they make up is fairly evenly distributed, which is why I think collapsing the variables wouldn't be a very good option. The following is the distribution for the 10 most frequent labels for the variable:

```
Government Of Tanzania    20.932829
Danida                     5.186667
Hesawa                     3.833314
World Bank                 2.289588
Rwssp                      2.230204
World Vision               2.186914
Kkkt                       2.135668
Unicef                     1.837318
Tasaf                      1.644216
Dhv                        1.457457
0                          1.362791
Private Individual         1.350987
Dwsp                       1.347113
```

Since label encoding and one-hot encoding wouldn't be a good option in this case, because of the large number of labels, 
*what would be a good encoding in this case?*

Comment: Have a look at [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels), [Encoding of categorical variables with high cardinality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411767/encoding-of-categorical-variables-with-high-cardinality) or [use embeddings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276128/how-do-you-encode-relationships-between-high-cardinality-categorical-features/420489#420489)