# Dealing with over 1000 categorical values (which are also a unique identifiers)

Tags: python, categorical-encoding, many-categories, feature-engineering

I am preparing my dataset for a logistic regression and need to check how best to handle a column with categorical values. As the dataset is for sales transactions, the column in question is the unique product identifier - of which there are over 1000 unique values. To complicate matters, all but 5 of these values are 7-8 digit integers (the remainder are strings). Examples below

```
*77789876*
*2213_usd_99*
```

Should I assign a unique integer 1 to 1374 to each of the original product codes, and then normalise the new int in order to get this to work?

I did consider putting the product code in the index, however I am not sure that will work as ultimately, I am trying to predict the probability that it will be sold on a given date, so will need to pass it in as a variable later on.

Any help or advice would be welcomed.

**UPDATE**
I tried a min max scaler an that ended up assigning the same values to multiple items i.e. 0.998

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels  How many observations do you have? What is the goal of the modeling? Tell us some more context ...

Comment: The ultimate goal is to be able to provide a probability score for the event that each of the products will be sold on a specific date (after reporting period). Therefore I need a unique identifier per product (and date of interest) to put into the LR equation to yield the final value.

Comment: You need to represent the product categories with dummy variables, your integer coding scheme **will not work**. But, somewhat depending on $n$, having a thousand parameters might be to much, also, the thousand products probably do not all act  differently! So some methods (see link in my first comment) such as the *fused lasso* will automatically shrink coefficient towards each other, making better predictions.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite tell what you are doing in enough detail.   What is needed is to convert your column of categorical variables to a contrast matrix of some sort. However, that is usually handled "magically" by the software (although not so magically you couldn't change the style of contrasts if you wished).

I *think* all you need is a column of strings (factors / categorical variables).  As I say, I don't know what package you are using.  But statsmodels (and packages built on that) will create a contrast matrix for you from the factor labels (the text) https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/contrasts.html. You shouldn't yourself need to worry about creating a column with unique integer variables, nor should you have to worry about creating the contrast matrix.

However, one little gotcha, where it is worth knowing a little about the "magic" is that with k = a number of 1000 different values, you will create a contrast matrix with k - 1 (a number one less than the number of different values).   If you have multiple rows of data per column, that is going to be a big matrix, which in turn might raise other problems.