# How to deal with 100+ levels in categorical variable in multiple linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data, many-categories

Im trying to model: `Y~x0+x1+x2+x3+x4`, were `Y` is a continous variable (cost), `x0` is the intercept, `x1` is a continous variable (days) and `x2-x4` are categorical variables with mulitple levels. The categorical variable `x2` have 156 levels (each level representing a different diagnosis code, i.e. lung cancer, migraine etc). I want to include `x2` in the model but I dont want 156 different dummy variables, were each dummy variable represent a diagnosis code.

Here is a picture of the frequencies of each level (censored):
[image]

About 2/3 of the levels are significant at 0.05, when `Y~x2`.

What is the best way to deal with this kind of problem in R?

Comment: Can you group the diagnosis codes into groups, thereby increasing your N for each group and maybe even providing more meaningful categoricals? e.g. group all the lung conditions, heart conditions, brain conditions, etc?

Comment: You could look into various contrast coding methods. But most likely just keeping the top k categories and a single other column is good enough.

Comment: Maybe this answers your Q:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146907/principled-way-of-collapsing-categorical-variables-with-many-levels