# Stepwise Regression for VAR or VECM Models

Tags: model-selection, vector-autoregression, stepwise-regression, vector-error-correction-model

I'm doing an analysis of integrated price series for two different types of crude oil. These crudes are priced off a differential to a main type ("marker"). I built an exogenous variable matrix that includes a main marker for Brent crude and dummy variables for day of the week. When I run the VAR, the t-stats for certain day of the week dummy variables are not significant (Thu/Fri). Is there any precedent for using stepwise regression with a VAR model to remove insignificant features?

Comment: It's generally best not to use stepwise regression at all (see: [Algorithms for automatic model selection](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/7290)), for anything...  Moreover, the tests of the individual levels of a categorical variable don't mean what people typically think they mean.  If you really need to combine levels of a categorical variable for some reason, you could try: [Principled way of collapsing categorical variables with many levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/146907/)

Comment: If you care about prediction, consider e.g. what the `bigtime` package in R does with VAR models.